# Register an Azure AD App Reg using New-AzADApplication PowerShell Module

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to upgrade from using AzureAD PowerShell to Az PowerShell for registering an App Reg. Previously I would do:

```
$RequiredResourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e","Scope"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1","Scope"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Role"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

New-AzureADApplication -RequiredResourceAccess $RequiredResourceAccess
```

And I think I need to do this in Az PowerShell:

```
$RequiredResourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphRequiredResourceAccess"
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphResourceAccess]
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e","Scope"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1","Scope"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess.Add($(New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Role"))
$RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

New-AzADApplication -RequiredResourceAccess $RequiredResourceAccess
```

But it keeps erroring with:

New-Object: Cannot find an overload for "MicrosoftGraphResourceAccess" and the argument count: "2".

Microsoft docs for this seems to be non-existent. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment. I eventually managed to find a solution using the following:

```
$RequiredResourceAccess = @{
  ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
  ResourceAccess = @(
      @{
          Id = "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e";
          Type = "Scope"
      },
      @{
          Id = "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1";
          Type = "Scope"
      },
      @{
          Id = "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214";
          Type = "Role"
      }
  )
}

New-AzADApplication -RequiredResourceAccess $RequiredResourceAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with multiple method for finding solution but unable to create AzureAD Application using `New-AzADApplication` of `New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphRequiredResourceAccess"`.

As of October 2021, the Az PowerShell module is still using the deprecated Azure AD Graph API for cmdlets targeting Azure Active Directory (for example, Get-AzAdApplication). However, Microsoft has stated that they will update the module to use the newer and supported Microsoft Graph API.

Reference : ***https://docs.ukcloud.com/articles/azure/azs-how-create-spn-powershell.html?tabs=tabid-1***

Would suggest you to reach out to ***[support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/)*** for further details and troubleshootig